# Nested template argument deduction

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I have some function that is templated on output type. This function then accepts an input argument that in its turn is templated on the output type. I do not want to specify the output type twice as that just clutters the api. In my world, I have told the compiler everything it needs to know to deduce this correctly but I cannot get it to work. Suggestions?

```
template<typename T>
struct TestStruct {};


template<typename T, template<typename> class U>
T testFunc(U<T> arg)
{
  return T{0};   
}

int main()
{
    testFunc<double>(TestStruct<double>{}); // Compiles
    testFunc<double>(TestStruct{});         // Does not compile  
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with `testFunc(TestStruct<double>{});` ? The second line has the problem that the function takes a `U<T>`, and you only supply `U`, which isn't a type on its own.

Comment: My idea was that I already gave the compiler both `U` and `T`. Then it should be able to deduce that "Ok TestStruct must be the `U` and `T` does fit in there. But nope :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** isn't with `testFunc` but with `TestStruct{}` as you're not passing a template argument and the corresponding template parameter of class template `TestStruct` doesn't have a default argument.

---

> I do not want to specify the output type twice

As you want to specify the `double` only once you can do:

```
template<typename T, template<typename> class U>
T testFunc(U<T> arg)
{
  return T{0};   
}

int main()
{
//----------------------vvvvvv-------------->only once as you want   
    testFunc(TestStruct<double>{});
//----------^------------------------------->no need to specify double here as it can be deduced   
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/osMxzdMdW)

As shown in the above modified program, we're only specifying `double` once when passing it as a template argument for `TestStruct`. The template argument for `T` of function template `testFunc` can be deduced.

Comment: Did not think about that, thanks! In my world I think the compiler should be able to perform Class Template Argument Deduction on `testFunc<double>(TestStruct{})`. But well!

Comment: @Martin The reason CTAD does not work in your example is because your class template `TestStruct` doesn't have a constructor from which to deduce the template parameter `T` and also you're not passing any argument when writing `TestStruct{}`. If you were to add a constructor to your class template and pass argument then CTAD will work. See [Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6zTf3ePvT). In the above demo, I've added a ctor and also passed an argument `4.4` using `testFunc<double>(TestStruct(4.4))`